# Want to display my 300+ organized links on a single webpage via my bookmarks on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, web-development

I have 2 main folders that branch out in my bookmarks called public and non-public.

I intended to find a way to be able to display specifically the public folder and everything inside on a single webpage of any sort. Couldn't find anything.

Obviously I am not a programmer and this is my first question and it would be awesome if anyone could point me in the right direction.

The purpose of this is to be able to just save a bookmark for example in a folder and woosh right into the page almost how like a tweet pops up. So far I have asked reddit /r/webdev but they said the bookmark APIs are not really helpful at all.

The page well is supposed to be a really solid collection of websites. I already have a manually updated google spreadsheet live on my blog right now, but if I update it with the amount of links I have now it would be ridiculous plus I add and delete things constantly because of dead websites etc...

If its not possible then I am willing to go as far as contacting the chrome team on this and I will wait, I am surprised no one has tried this yet and to be honest I could easily imagine the outcome of this to be submitted to award sites all over the place.

Comment: 1) export your bookmarks 2) order them with a loop 3) display 4) profit

Comment: Exporting them to HTML just give the parent folder text and its ugly as hell. Plus I can't export only the public folder it will take all the links I have. And to be honest I wish I knew what number 2 meant

Comment: I want to provide the list I exported here but I don't know if that is allowed. (took me 2 minutes to delete the non-public links from the HTML)

Comment: What are you displaying where? is this a website? You want folder on your computer to update what is displayed on your website?

Comment: I want the bookmarks I sync with my chrome to update what is displayed. I sync everything with my gmail.

Comment: Chrome does not support auto export bookmarks. So, you can parse a JSON file of bookmarks in chrome profile folder, get the required bookmarks and put them in required format(Write a utility or script for this and schedule it to run)...read this as well: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/37992-Help-parsing-json-based-chromium-bookmarks-files

Comment: I will look into that suggestion. But what if I got an extension or userscript (think firefox, there are portals for userscripts to work on chrome) to auto export? Or when you say chrome doesn't support that does that mean its because chrome literally can't auto export